# Resharper warning in switch case "The source expression always matches the provided pattern"

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Resharper is showing a warning "The source expression always matches the provided pattern" and underlining the `case int` of the last case statement.
The roslyn fix is "to object pattern" and changes it to `case { } upperLvl when upperlevel >= 20`

Can anybody enlighten me as to why this warning is shown and if I should apply that change?

```
public static decimal CalculateCouponValue(int level)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            default:
                return 20;
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
                return 25;
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                return 30;
            case 14:
            case 15:
            case 16:
                return 35;
            case 17:
            case 18:
            case 19:
                return 40;
            case int upperLvl when upperLvl >= 20: //The source expression always matches the provided pattern
                return 50;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `level` is always an `int` (it's declared as `int level`), so a pattern of `case int` doesn't add anything. That said, I'd personally keep it.

Comment: Which version of Resharper and C# are you using? I didn't see any warnings at my end

Comment: It just seems like case {} upperLevel would be a different check, which is why I think this warning makes no sense here, where there is a when clause behind it.

Comment: It's Rider Version 2019.3.1 (but the same thing happens if I open it in VS with Resharper 2019.3.1)
In a netstandard2.0 targeted project with LangVersion 8.0

Comment: actually you say: "in case of level is an int", and that's worth a warning, cause it always is. Don't know whether any other syntax is worse or better.

Comment: Is there a way to say "in case of level is an int larger than 19" which does not trigger the warning. Because obviously it always is an int, but I don't think it should trigger a warning if there is a when clause at the end of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper issues this warning because expression of type `int` indeed always matches *type pattern* `int upperLvl`, in other words specifying the same type is redundant. The proposed transformation of *type pattern* into *object pattern* (`{}`) gives equivalent semantics (you may check it [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfYwL58GQpuRxJSAExhgAlgFsAhgBsqKsAFdligC4xKEDQAcIAOwBqKjTA6zTO0spgA3GMq4i6BRj9IBnAHdZHTAAC1IOJ1d3ER8vXwSpGAAzRS0dEFjEnwwAdlIsAAYAbiyEsEU/GFIADkzvbMYKqtIATnrGpsrqnEKOzt88goBWUobO5p6cfonu0hwsGcbJ+eIlgfJ84hKy3xWcFHXE/eGj8rnxM8ah4lHdn33cq4eLuvuulpx294ShlB3xss5jR+KRjEYYFAADLOVQBUIwUxgowQ6Gw0gAPgAvAU+qQAPT4gAqCP8higYGqMAQRlgfj8sjMpBUAUUAE8/KQlCEEZydKTaRBnLJpJJSEZdHooKYfoN8sMAdlBIDlfwgA=)) but personally I prefer *var pattern* in such cases:

```cs
case var upperLvl when upperLvl >= 20:
    return 50;
```

which also preseves the original semantics. The *var pattern* **always succeeds** but kind of indicates that you just want to introduce new variable here.

Note that all these options are equivalent here because you're switching on expression of *value type* but there are subtle differences when it comes to *reference types*.

Let's say you're switching on some `string` value:

```
public static decimal GetDiscountByCode(string code)
{
    switch (code.ToUpper())
    {
        case "XMAS2020":
            return 25;
        case "NEWYEAR2020":
            return 20;
        case string specialCode
          when TryExtractDiscount(specialCode, out var discount):
            return discount;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Here *type pattern* `string specialCode` performs the **null check** meaning that `null` value doesn't match this pattern.

Replacing the *type pattern* with *object pattern* `{} specialCode` is equivalent because *object pattern* **also performs null check**.

But using the *var pattern* instead would change the semantics because as I mentioned earlier it **always succeeds** without performing any additional checks.

You can quickly check how C# *lowers* all these high-level constructs at wonderful website https://sharplab.io/.

And finally. The decision on whether to apply the fix proposed by ReSharper is always up to you! If you really prefer the type pattern syntax you may change severity of this particular inspection from `Warning` to `Hint` or even disable it completely: just press `Alt+Enter` on highlighted code, expand the menu item **Inspection: "The source expression is always of pattern's type" | Configure inspection severity** and select another severity which works best for you :)